# How to call external function in an external file. C

Tags: c, linux

I have one base library written in C. And other external extensions/definitions files. With a simple search tool the base library (when is used) can search in a directory for extensions libraries. Without telling the compiler which files it are. Then the C program can call a function in that external file.

So i want to run a function in a external file. I can choose which file I want to run the function from at running time. (Ex, I enter that the file is located at ./external_file at running time) (NOT COMPILE TIME!). Is this possible?

I need to read a return from the function, I need to wait until the function is finished, I need to call the function with arguments and it must be possible that the program at run time can choose the file and function.

Is this possible? Yes, program files does contains function names (with names). Only I need to know HOW do I call that function in a external file at run time.

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: Check this: man dlopen

Comment: Normally, you'd use dynamic link libraries (DLL's) for this, but the details are dependent on the OS.

Comment: It is operating system specific

Comment: Its linux. Sorry that I forget that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dlopen` function to load a shared library (i.e. a .so file) at runtime, then use `dlsym` to get the functions to call.

For example, suppose you had the following library file:

mylib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(int a)
{
    printf("in f1, a=%d\n", a);
}

int f2(char *s)
{
    printf("in f2, s=%s\n", s);
    return *s;
}
```

Then you compile it to a shared library:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -c mylib.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -o libmylib.so mylib.o
```

You can call these functions as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    // get a handle to the shared library
    void *handle = dlopen("./libmylib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        printf("dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    // get a pointer to the function to call
    void (*myf1)(int) = dlsym(handle, "f1");
    if (!myf1) {
        printf("dlsym 1 failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
    myf1(4);

    // get a pointer to another function to call
    int (*myf2)(char *) = dlsym(handle, "f2");
    if (!myf2) {
        printf("dlsym 2 failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("rval=%d\n", myf2("hello"));

    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you need to know at compile time what the function signatures look like so you can call them correctly.

Comment: What does -Wall and -Wextra

Comment: @SmileDeveloper Those emit more verbose warnings.  Highly recommended to use them for all compiles.

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic libraries - most OS's provide support for loading a library given a name and getting the address of the function to call.

In windows see LoadLibrary and ProcAddress. In linux see dlopen and dlsym.